# Generic Method for filling audit fields

Tags: c#, wcf

Generic Method for filling audit fields

I want to fill the audit fields for each entity when they are added or modified.

For example, `Customer` entity has `CreatedDate`, `UpdatedDate`.
Same for Order entity which has `CreatedDate`, `UpdatedDate`.

I can update them in the `AddCustomer` or `UpdateCustomer` methods Or `NewOrder`, `UpdateOrder` methods.

For `AddCustomer`:

```
customer.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
customer.UpdatedDate= DateTime.Now;
```

For `UpdateCustomer`:

```
customer.UpdatedDate= DateTime.Now
```

What I want to do instead of repeating the code in every method, can I have generic method which accepts generic type and updates?

```
private void FillAuditFields<T>(ref T entity)
{
}
```

What should I do inside the `FillAuditFields` (if I can) to say `entity.CreatedBy`, `entity.UpdatedBy` . Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

No need for generics at all, you just need your Customer & Order classes implement an interface such as:

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    DateTime CreatedDate{get;set;}
    DateTime UpdatedDate{get;set;}
}
```

And have 2 methods somewhere appropriate

```
public void AuditableCreated(IAuditable auditable)
{
    auditable.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
public void AuditableUpdated(IAuditable auditable)
{
    auditable.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let your entities implement an interface with the fields you want to set on all entities and restrict T  to classes implementing that interface using the 'where' clause.